# I am looking for an RSS slide show service

Tags: webapp-rec, rss

I am looking for an service which will present me several RSS feeds (text+images) as an slide show. I would happily use Google Reader play, but I found no proper way, to control what feeds it will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing google reader feeds and play them in reader play. If you hover over the feed you want (or a whole tag folder) and click on the dropdown arrow, you have a choice to 'View in Reader Play'.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Muy gracias! Let me add, that you have to change the language settings of google reader to English to be able to use this feature.